# Inside the settouch interceptor unable to call the functions in android?

Tags: android

In my application I am using a popup window. For dismissing the popup window when the user touches outside, I am using the **ORDER LIST PW CODING** coding below, the pop window dismiss function works perfectly but not able to call

```
Submenu_listtask = new Submenu_list();
Submenu_listtask.execute();
```

this function inside `setTouchInterceptor` its not working. Can any one know please help me.

**ORDER LIST PW CODING**

```
order_list_pw.setTouchInterceptor(new OnTouchListener() {
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) {
                        //Unable to call this function
                        Submenu_listtask = new Submenu_list();
                        Submenu_listtask.execute();

                        order_list_pw.dismiss();

                        Log.v("Name", "Name");

                        return true;
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return `true` at the end of `onTouch()` as returning `false` only enables you to catch `ACTION_DOWN` event